# ggplot2: standard error ribbons not matching the plot lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add error bar ribbons to my ggplot, but for some reason the shading doesn't match the plotted lines. This is the second time I encounter this problem and I cannot figure out for the life of me why this happens. Initially, I thought this may happen due to the way some variables are defined as factors, but I still get this problem even if I change their formatting. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Plot with incorrect ribbons]

Data frame:

```
    m<- structure(list(sound = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Silence", "English"), class = "factor"), `Reading condition` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("normal", "trailing mask"
), class = "factor"), diff = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Easy questions", "Difficult questions"
), class = "factor"), Mean = c(0.283, 0.36, 0.183, 0.227, 0.19, 
0.347, 0.197, 0.333), SD = c(0.500558971667007, 0.34814947033031, 
0.497195715406262, 0.447163568809774, 0.49804988833968, 0.361515576848703, 
0.498812908487118, 0.373926502247132), SE = c(0.100111794333401, 
0.0696298940660619, 0.0994391430812524, 0.0894327137619548, 0.099609977667936, 
0.0723031153697406, 0.0997625816974236, 0.0747853004494263)), .Names = c("sound", 
"Reading condition", "diff", "Mean", "SD", "SE"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), idvars = c("sound", "mask", "diff"), rdimnames = list(structure(list(
    sound = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("English", 
    "Silence"), class = "factor"), mask = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diff = c("difficult", "easy", "difficult", "easy", "difficult", 
    "easy", "difficult", "easy")), .Names = c("sound", "mask", 
"diff"), row.names = c("English_No_difficult", "English_No_easy", 
"English_Yes_difficult", "English_Yes_easy", "Silence_No_difficult", 
"Silence_No_easy", "Silence_Yes_difficult", "Silence_Yes_easy"
), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "accuracy", class = "factor"), result_variable = structure(1:2, .Label = c("M", 
"SD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("variable", "result_variable"
), row.names = c("accuracy_M", "accuracy_SD"), class = "data.frame")), class = "data.frame")
```

Graph code:

```
library(ggplot2)
limits <- aes(ymax = m$Mean + m$SE, ymin=m$Mean - m$SE)

Dplot<- ggplot(data= m, aes(x=sound, y= Mean, color= `Reading condition`, 
                            fill= `Reading condition`,
                            group=`Reading condition`, shape=`Reading condition`,
                            linetype=`Reading condition`))+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")+ scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2")+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#E3E5E6", size=0.7), 
                     axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size=1),
                     panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1, fill = NA))+
  geom_line(size=2) + ylim(0, 0.5)+
  geom_point(size=7)+ scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.2,0.2))+
  #scale_y_continuous(limits- c(0,0.50))+
  xlab("\n Background sound")+ ylab("Comprehension above chance level (%)")+ 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", family="serif"), legend.text=element_text(size=20,family="serif"),legend.key.width=unit(2,"cm"),
        legend.key.height=unit(1,"cm"), strip.text=element_text(size=20, family="serif"),
        title=element_text(size=20, family="serif"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=20, face="bold", family="serif"), axis.title.y = element_text(size=20, face="bold", family="serif"), 
        axis.text=element_text(size=20, family="serif"), 
        panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black"), 
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "#000000", size=1))+
  geom_ribbon(limits, alpha=0.15, colour=NA) +
  facet_grid(.~ diff) + theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20,  face="bold",family="serif"),
                                 strip.background = element_rect(fill="#F5F7F7", colour="black", size=1.5),
                                 legend.key = element_rect(colour = "#000000", size=1))
```

Comment: Don't use `$` subsetting in `aes`. If you drop that, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the data frame and subsetting to a variable (e.g. with `$`) can cause weird things to happen in ggplot. You never need such subsetting, as the data frame is already specified to a `data` parameter at some point (likely in the first `ggplot(...)` call). Data, like aesthetics, is inherited from `ggplot` to geoms and stats, too, so unless you're changing the data, there is no reason to worry about re-specifying its origin. (If you *do* want to change the data frame used, specify the `data` parameter of the relevant geom or stat.)

Dropping the `m$`s will fix the problem. Rearranging and simplifying so the logic is more obvious,

```r
library(ggplot2)

m <- data.frame(sound = c("English", "English", "English", "English", "Silence", "Silence", "Silence", "Silence"), 
                `Reading condition` = c("normal", "normal", "trailing mask", "trailing mask", "normal", "normal", "trailing mask", "trailing mask"), 
                diff = c("Difficult questions", "Easy questions", "Difficult questions", "Easy questions", "Difficult questions", "Easy questions", "Difficult questions", "Easy questions"), 
                Mean = c(0.283, 0.36, 0.183, 0.227, 0.19, 0.347, 0.197, 0.333), 
                SD = c(0.500558971667007, 0.34814947033031, 0.497195715406262, 0.447163568809774, 0.49804988833968, 0.361515576848703, 0.498812908487118, 0.373926502247132), 
                SE = c(0.100111794333401, 0.0696298940660619, 0.0994391430812524, 0.0894327137619548, 0.099609977667936, 0.0723031153697406, 0.0997625816974236, 0.0747853004494263), 
                check.names = FALSE)

ggplot(m, aes(x = sound, y = Mean, ymax = Mean + SE, ymin = Mean - SE, 
              color = `Reading condition`, fill = `Reading condition`, 
              group = `Reading condition`)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.15, colour = NA) +
    facet_grid(. ~ diff)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! That actually makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Alistaire’s correct answer this way: under the hood, ggplot takes your starting data.frame(s) and applies all the transforms, scales, and stats that your ggplot code demands. The graphic is then generated in the resulting coordinate system.

By anchoring your aes for the ribbon to your global environment data.frame with m$..., you’re specifying pre-transform, pre-stat, pre-scale coordinates... sometimes your original coordinate system might be confusingly close to the hidden coordinate system so that your elements appear, but just a bit off, as you’re seeing.